# Proving that inclusion map is open using characteristic property of the subspace topology

Tags: general-topology

In Lee's book he uses the characteristic property of the subspace topology:

Suppose X is a topological space and $S \subset X$ is a subspace. For any topological space Y, a map $f: Y \rightarrow S$ is continuous iff $r_S \circ f : Y \rightarrow X$ is continuous, where $r_S$ is the inclusion map $r_S : S \rightarrow X$

Now to show that the inclusion map $r_S : S \rightarrow X$ is continuous he argues by saying that the identity is always continuous and uses the fact that the following diagram commutes:

[image]

Which to me looks as if he's proving $r_S$ is continuous by arguing that $r_S$ is continuous, which is probably not what he means.

So I think that I must not completely understand the usefulness of the characteristic property theorem. Could someone help me maybe by explaining his proof please?

Comment: No, he is arguing that $r_s$ is continuous because $id$ is. Put every player into the universal property (i.e. $Y=S$ and $f=id$) and see that its all ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the universal property for $Y= S$ and $f=\mathrm{Id}_S$: it says

> $\mathrm{Id}_S$ is continuous iff $r_S \circ \mathrm{Id}_S$ is continuous.

The latter is just $r_S$ by the commutative diagram, which is trivial to check.

And the identity on space is **always** continuous (just as all constant maps), so we conclude that as the left function is continuous, so is $r_S$.